# Одна таблица для данных разного уровня вложенности

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Есть таблица с полями id, pid, name. Данные из этой таблицы выводятся по уровням вложенности в зависимости от значения pid.

Если pid=0, то это данные первого уровня. Далее каждое значение первого уровня разветвляется на подгруппы значений второго уровня, которые отличаются уже разными pid =3, 8, 26 ,32 и т.д.

Второй уровень разветвляется на третий уровень, тут данные тоже соответственно группируются по значениям pid.

Как такая таблица администрируется? По какому принципу присваиваются значения pid, если требуется добавить новое значение, скажем, для второго или третьего уровня?

Comment: pid скорее всего просто ссылается на родительскую запись. Если у вас есть запись с pid=3 то посмотрите, видимо ее ордительская запись (с первого уровня) имеет id=3

Comment: Насколько я понял Вы про "хранение иерархических/древовидных данных в базе данных". [К примеру как тут](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/treedb.htm).

Comment: Что интересно pid не ссылается на родительскую запись, например все записи первого уровня имеют pid=0 и таких записей несколько, зато потомки каждой записи первого уровня делятся на группы с разными pid,

Comment: И сколько у вас подгрупп на втором уровне, больше 3х ?

Comment: Посмотрел подробнее, спасибо, Mike, как вы говорили , уловил кажется зависимость именно по id. Подгрупп да, много, больше чем три

Comment: Странно если их на втором уровне больше 3х, 2й уровень весь ссылается на 3 записи первого уровня. третий уровень своими pid уже смотрит на id записей второго уровня.

Comment: Тут такая схема как я понял, первый уровень первая запись имеет pid=0 и id=1, второй уровень - потомки первой записи все имеют pid=1, и так с каждой записью, третий уровень не проверял, но думаю там по аналогии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае pid - наверняка должно расшифровываться как "Parent ID". В таком дереве для каждого дочернего элемента в pid записывается идентификатор родительского. Для корневых элементов обычно указывается либо 0, либо null. Выглядит это дерево таким образом:

```
Родитель1     [id=1,pid=0]
-- Потомок1   [id=2,pid=1]
-- Потомок2   [id=3,pid=1]
---- Потомок3 [id=4,pid=3]

Родитель2     [id=5,pid=0]

Родитель3     [id=6,pid=0]
-- Потомок4   [id=7,pid=6]
```

Администрируется очень просто - во время добавления элемента всего лишь указывается его родительский идентификатор.

С выводом сложнее. Чаще всего - это рекурсивная функция. Если речь идет об агрегации большого количества данных из БД, применяют искуственное ограничение на вложенность и соответствующее количество вложенных запросов/джоинов в запросе элементов.

Статей на эту тему много, например: https://habrahabr.ru/post/226741/ или http://habrahabr.ru/post/46659/